# Flash AS3 - Best 3D engine for interfaces (pre-molehill)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, away3d

I'm looking into 3D engines for AS3 interface work, and I'm acclimated with Papervision (but it has not been updated since 2009).

Is Papervision still the best choice for interfaces or are other alternatives like Away3D and Sandy3D worth looking at? I went through their demos and I was not very impressed. However, demos may not be reflective of the API's true potential, so that is why I ask you guys :)

If it helps, I'm looking for a 3D engine that will handle interactive flat planes well and perhaps simple shapes (such as cubes). Again I do a mostly interface work so I'm not trying to build a game in 3D or anything... it will most likely be integrated with other Flash elements.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's not time critical, I would hold off and wait for Flash 11 to be released, which will be before 2012. In the mean time, you could [try Stage3D](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/features/stage3d.html) (AKA Molehill) in development, so you can become familiar with it and then publicly release your work when Flash is updated for everyone.

Comment: Hi Tim. I do plan to look into Molehill when it is matured, but I need to get up to speed with 3D API's beforehand (for work purposes). This also means I'll be delayed a bit with Molehill until it reaches high enough user penetration. I'm sure I'll be bugging you guys in the future when Molehill-powered API's are cranked out but for now I need my inferior-tech solution :)

Comment: The Stage3D API is pretty low level, unless you are writing your own framework (or experimenting) you probably don't need to know much about it. You definitely do want a framework that supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say use Away3d instead of Papervision or sandy3d

here are some of the reasons

- away3d is a fork of pv3d, so if you're familiar with pv3d going into away3d should b e pretty easy.
- away3d is actively maintained, last post on pv3d blog is more than a year old
- away3d has been working with adobe on molehill/stage3d support, so once it is available in FP11, you'll have access to that.

alternatively there is the [alternativa platform](http://blog.alternativaplatform.com/en/), which has been hailed for its speed and tools. And now offers a free licence.

Comment: I did a bunch of research after you posted, with Flare3d, Alternativa, n00b3D ... Away3D is definitely the best pick for my situation because it's (mostly) familiar, it will be ready for molehill, and it's FREE personally or for commercial purposes :) Thanks a bunch!